# Running QML demo based on symbian code on meego

Tags: qt-creator, meego-harmattan

Has anybody successfully tried to run the flickr demo from QtSDK (1.1.4) on n9 ? I have tried and it was not working -- showing only (almost) empty bar in the device. On the Qt Creator, the console error is saying that 'com.nokia.symbian 1.1 not installed' -- which is obviously what is used in the qml import in the demo files. My question is how can I make the flickr demo running on meego target ? Do I miss any qt-quick component for meego ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change import by com.meego.nokia.com 1.0
The api is pretty much the same.

(i ven't try)

Comment: As i have moved away from this issue as of now, i accept this answer for some hint to anyone facing the same problem.